# How to allow SSH access to only one domain name on a server hosting multiple domains?

Tags: ubuntu, service, domain

I have an Ubuntu server hosting example1.com and example2.com. Both names are pointing to the same IP address.

I've configured Apache and it's working ok by using /var/www/example1 for the first and /var/www/example2 to the second domain.

<del>What I would like to achieve next is to disallow all other service requests on both domain, except allowing SSH connections to example1.com.</del>

What I would like to achieve next is to allow SSH connections only to example1.com.

How on earth is this done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no simple sshd equivalent to apache's VirtualHosts.

Typically what you'll need to do, though, is configure the ssh settings for each user to `chroot` them into a single folder hierarchy.

Regarding your other question, what exactly do you mean by "disallow all other service requests"?

Comment: Never mind. My mind is flowing too quickly after a loooong day at work. I'm not going to even bother to try to explain what I was thinking while writing that because it wouldn't make sense anyway. But thank you for answering. :)

Comment: @budwiser - you need a beer (hopefully of better quality than your namesake, though).